# Как установить JVM без прав администратора?

Tags: java, установка, jvm

Всем привет. Хочу на рабочем компе писать и запускать код на Java, но не могу установить JVM из-за отсутствия прав администратора. Среду разработки я установил, т.к. если устанавливать не в Program Files, то возможно обойти необходимость админки, но JVM без админки никак не могу установить. Подскажите, есть ли возможность запустить JVM без прав админа? Может, есть какие-то среды со встроенной JVM или portable версии?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Портабл версии https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk16-downloads.html смотри "Compressed Archive".

В IDE нужно указать параметры JAVA_HOME или ссылку на bin/java.exe

Со встроенной явой работают IDE от JetBrains.